# Vuejs and SSRS Report Connection in web.config

Tags: reporting-services, vuejs2, web-config, ssrs-2008

I have an application build with vuejs, and i want to connect SSRS reporting service, how to best practice connect my application with SSRS, with config username and password in web.config

sorry for my bad english
thanks
ik